# Can a hard link break the file system structure?

Tags: filesystems, symlink, hard-link

I want a very simple example of how can a hard link break the file system structure.

I saw somewhere that people say it's because of loops, however, I can make a loop with a soft link and so I still want to know what makes hard link break the file system?

Comment: Please ask one question per question. I chose to answer the first question in your post. If you want, ask the second question in a separate post. But don't just repost it, you need to explain what you want better: have you read the Wikipedia article? Which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard links to directories that can break the filesystem structure. Hard links to other types of files aren't a problem. For example:

```
mkdir foo
ln foo foo/self
rmdir foo
```

`rmdir foo` doesn't actually remove the directory since it has a remaining link — the `self` entry inside `foo` itself. `foo` has become detached from the filesystem; it can't be reached anymore, but it still exists. Forbidding hard links to directories prevents this problem. There are garbage-collected filesystems where a detached directory tree is automatically reclaimed, but they've never really taken (it's a significant effort for hardly any benefit).

Another problem is with tools that traverse a directory tree. If hard links to directories are allowed, then these tools would have to remember all previously-seen directories and skip them, or else they would loop forever when encountering a directory which is a subdirectory of itself (or of a child of itself, etc.).

Loops with symbolic links aren't a problem. If the target of the symbolic link is removed, the existence of the symlink doesn't matter. In recursive traversals, symlinks aren't followed (unless explicitly requested).